# kubernetes service external IP assigned to node secondary interface

Tags: amazon-ec2, interface, kubernetes

I have a two node kubernetes cluster deployed on ec2. One of the nodes is attached with a secondary network interface as below.

```
NODE 1 --> eth0 (ip1).  
NODE 2 --> eth0 (ip2), eth1 (ip3)
```

We are creating a Load Balancer service with `externalIPs` as `ip3`,

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: test-service
  namespace: test-namespace
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: test-service
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 12222
    targetPort: 12222
    name: media-dev
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 12223
    targetPort: 12223
    name: dev-test
  externalIPs:
  - ip3
```

But this doesn't work and we will not able to access ip3.
Please let me know if there is any what that I can stream traffic from secondary interface (ip3) to the pod.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set kubelet on Node2 to use ip3 from eth1 by setting following flag:

```
--node-ip <ip3>
```

in

```
/etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d/10-kubeadm.conf
```

and then

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl restart kubelet
```

More info about kubelet:
https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kubelet/

Comment: Thanks  @JakubBujny for your quick help. I got through the documentation, it looks like we can have single IP address assigned to --node-ip flag. Can this be used in any way so that both IP belonging to eth0 and eth1 works the same way.